# appium with python: appium stop responding after 5 minutes sleep

Tags: python, appium

I am using `appium` version `1.13.0`

In my scenario i need to wait at some point 5 minutes and i noticed that after this 5 minutes of sleep the `appium` stop responding.

Is someones know about this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have [`newCommandTimeout` capability](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) set to 300 (or less) seconds, you can increase it to the desired value as:

```
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['newCommandTimeout'] = '600'
#etc
```

See [Timeout Capabilities](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Timeout+Capabilities) article for more information